# Attach/parent decal to character clothing

Tags: modeling

Thank you for any help.
I have a character that I created in fuse with clothing.  I'm trying to attach my logo in blender to the shirt.  I can do it no problem with subdivision surface and then shrink-wrap modifiers but when. Animation goes the decal does not move with character.  I've tried to parent to object buy that doesn't work either.